# How sklearn classifier works for multiclass non numeric labels?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

1. How to use sklearn classifiers for multiple output data?
2. Do I need to encode the non numeric labels first or is taken care by default in the classifier? If there is any default encoding the classifier is using, what is that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sklearn provides the module for [multioutput regression and classification](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.multioutput).
2. Yes, you need to encode the non numeric labels. You can use the [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) module for this.

Comment: I think I described it wrongly, my data is like iris dataset. Each input is having only single output only but the classes are multiple. So it's a multi class single output problem. What to use for such data?

Comment: In your case, it should be enough encode the target via LabelEncoder.